# Can anyone please have a look at my SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my SQL (MySQL) command:

```
SELECT pp.pluginid
FROM plugins pp
WHERE 
    (pp.limit=-1)
    OR
    (pp.limit>(select count(a.pluginid) from ads a where a.pluginid = pp.pluginid))
ORDER BY count(a.pluginid)
```

The last line (order by) doesn't work, and I understand why (because I don't output this value from a subquery). But I don't know how, and don't know what command to look for.

Fixed!!!
Here's what I did:

```
SELECT pp.pluginid, (select count(a.pluginid) from ads a where a.pluginid = pp.pluginid) as bb
FROM plugins pp
WHERE 
    (pp.limit=-1)
    OR
    (pp.limit>(select count(a.pluginid) from ads a where a.pluginid = pp.pluginid))
ORDER BY bb
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a join and a group by, like this:

```
SELECT pp.pluginid,pp.limit
FROM plugins pp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ads a ON a.pluginid = pp.pluginid
GROUP BY pp.pluginid
HAVING pp.limit=-1 OR pp.limit > COUNT(1)
ORDER BY COUNT(1)
```

Note that you need to use `HAVING` in place of `WHERE` because the condition uses an aggregation.

Here is a [link to a demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65658/9).

Comment: is there a way only to output pp.pluginid? (keeping same structure)

Comment: @JohnSmith Absolutely - you can wrap it in another select, and project out the unwanted column. Take a look: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65658/14).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but try:

```
SELECT pp.pluginid, count(a.pluginid) nads
  FROM plugins pp
  JOIN ads a ON a.pluginid = pp.pluginid
  WHERE pp.limit = -1
     OR pp.limit > nads
  GROUP BY a.pluginid
  ORDER BY nads
```

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY clause require db column name